# How to get data from two different object with same field if there is no relation between objects using SOQL

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

How to get data from tow different object with same field if there is no relation between two objects using SOQL there is one common field between two objects.

I am trying the below query :

```
select Id,field1,field2,**commonfield** from **obj1** 
  where Feature_ID__c in (select **commonfield** from **obj2** )
```

Getting error like semi join sub selects can only query id fields, cannot use.

How to write the SOQL  for this?

Answer (score 2):

Primary or foreign key are the only fields supported in a subquery, as the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm#semi_and_anti) states:

> A semi-join is a subquery on another object in an IN clause to restrict the records returned. [...]
> **The subquery can filter by ID (primary key) or reference (foreign key) fields**.

Therefore to fix this issue you should run separate queries. You also need a Set to hold every value of `commonfield` from the second object, then loop over `SELECT commonfield FROM obj2` to populate it. Now you can run the query on obj1 `WHERE Feature_ID__c in :commonFieldSet`.

Assuming that `Feature_ID__c` is a String:

```java
Set<String> featureIds = new Set<String>();
for (Obj2 record : [SELECT commonField FROM obj2]) {
    featureIds.add(record.commonField);
}

List<Obj1> something = [SELECT Id,field1,field2,commonfield FROM obj1 WHERE Feature_ID__c in :featureIds];
```